# I need to join three tables, group the results by one column, and display the highest value from another column

Tags: mysql, sql, join, greatest-n-per-group

Say I have three tables:

- `users` with names IDs
- `emails` containing rows which have their email address
- `messages` containing rows which contain the dates and titles of their emails

the second and third tables can all be matched to the first using the user's ID of course.

I want a query which will return *each user once only*, their email address and the date of their *most recent* message.

If I use this:

```
SELECT name,email,title,date
FROM users
JOIN emails ON users.id = emails.user_id
JOIN messages ON messages.user_id = emails.user_id
group by name
order by date desc
```

I don't get the most recent message, because the ordering has happened after the joining and the grouping. I get one email each from my users, and the emails are sorted by their date.

Can this be done in one join? What am I missing?

Pastebin for a dummy database you can use: http://pastebin.com/1x273aEe -- the actual database is not exactly like this, but it's the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN emails b
            ON a.ID = b.user_ID
        INNER JOIN messages c
            ON a.ID = c.user_ID
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT user_id, MAX(date) maxDate
            FROM messages
            GROUP BY user_ID
        ) d ON c.user_ID = d.user_ID AND
                c.date = d.maxDate
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fac90/2)

Comment: Hi, that's working exactly as required on JSFiddle, thank you. But curiously, it's not working as expected on my local setup, client and server both 5.1.44. Anyway, I've got the idea.

Comment: what results are you getting on your local machine?

Comment: I'm getting duplicates. The correct four results appear in the correct order, but then they appear again. It works on the production server though, different version of MySQL.

Comment: add `DISTINCT`, eg `SELECT DISTINCT a.*, b.*, c.* ....`. I guess you have duplicate rows in your table messages.

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much. Any idea why an older version of MySQL should behave that way?

Comment: the version doesn't matter at all. it depends on the records on the table. it happens that the most recent message on the table seems to be duplicated. `:D`

Comment: For the record, there were duplicates in the dummy table. My mistake. DISTINCT is not required.